# Failed to automatically update constraints

Tags: ios11, swift4, xcode9

I am getting the `Failure to automatically update constraints` error when trying to use the auto layout to Add, Reset, or Update any restraints on any viewController after updating to xCode 9. Any ideas? I have already cleaned and restarted my Mac.

Still have not found a solution for this. I narrowed it down to any viewController with a collectionView inside it. Any ideas?

Comment: For people having this problem - Apple has been notified and said they are working on a fix so expect it in 9.1.

Comment: Getting this same error, hoping they fix it soon...

Comment: Revert back to xCode 8 until it's fixed is what I did. I will post here when they do fix it.

Comment: I'm also having many issues on interface builder, slow and having those constraints errors. Does the project saved on xcode 9 works back to 8? I also found they have a beta 9.1, does any one tested on the beta?

Comment: Update: I just installed beta 9.1 and seems to be working fine, I will keep fixing my project with it. Hope Apple release XCODE 9.1 soon.

Comment: I can also confirm the beta works. I can confirm that you can convert it back to xCode 8.6? or whatever the most recent 8.# is.

Comment: that beta 9.1 is works ? i also got this problem ..

Comment: Yes, the beta 9.1 works with this specific problem; however it is a beta and I am sure it's filled with other bugs they are fixing. I would wait for official release.

Comment: I'm also getting this error, but with any view controller that is embedded in a navigation controller.

Comment: I just downloaded Xcode beta 2 build 9B46 and updating the constraints seem to be working much better, not perfect, but certainly better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For everyone following this. xCode 9.0.1 is out. Tested and it fixes this error. I haven’t be able to reproduce.

Comment: Its 9.0.1 and not 9.1

Answer (score 5):

I got also this error, when I tried to update/add etc. my constraints [error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3ka8.png)

I use Xcode Version 9.0 (9A235) and I spent the whole day figuring it out. I solved my problem by deleting a segmentctrl in the navigation bar. all my controller with a segctrl in the nav bar seems to bug.

I made a video with a new project
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TOTzCfDoFNA&feature=youtu.be

Comment: This will effect the entire project or solely the viewController?

Comment: for me it was only the view controllers with the segmentcontroll, I added it programmatically. after that everything worked normal. I guess it's a bug, that will be fixed soon. Xcode 9 seem full of bugs, the map view lags like hell.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the navigationbar in your view controller in storyboard .For me it is working well.

Comment: For me it was the UiCollectionViews that was causing the problem - can’t just remove something when it’s part of the app.

Answer (score 0):

@Rumbel you are correct , its a bug from apple in Xcode 9.0

watch this youtube 
[segment control bug in IOS 11 and Xcode 9.0](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TOTzCfDoFNA&feature=youtu.be)

Comment: It's not just the segment control.