# Failed to automatically update constraints, iOS 11 Xcode 9

Tags: swift, xcode, storyboard, ios11

Xcode 9 repeatedly gives me this error everytime I try to Add Missing Constraints or Reset to Suggested Constraints in a view controller that is attached to a navigation controller.

[image]

If I remove the segue connection between the navigation and view controller, adding missing constraints in the view controller works perfectly. This functionality appears to break whenever it is embedded in a navigation controller.

Is there a solution to this bug? I've only seen one other user having this problem on Stackoverflow. I've tested this in three of my Xcode projects and it's barring me from completing any work at all on my apps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to automatically update constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46335040/failed-to-automatically-update-constraints)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is a known bug in Xcode 9. I just downloaded Xcode 8 from the Apple Developer Portal and everything is working fine using that.

https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?name=Xcode